# Python multiprocessing: Reading a file and updating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

Lets assume that I have a text file with only 2 rows as follows:

```
File.txt:

100022441   @DavidBartonWB Guarding Constitution  
100022441   RT @frankgaffney 2nd Amendment Guy.
```

First column is user id and second column is user tweet. I'd like to read the above text file and update the following dictionary:

```
d={'100022441':{'@frankgaffney': 0, '@DavidBartonWB': 0}}.
```

Here is my code:

```
def f(line):
    data = line.split('\t')
    uid = data[0]
    tweet = data[1]
    if uid in d.keys():
        for gn in d[uid].keys():
            if gn in tweet:
                return uid, gn, 1
            else:
                return uid, gn, 0
p = Pool(4)
with open('~/File.txt') as source_file:
    for uid, gn, r in p.map(f, source_file):
        d[uid][gn] += r
```

So basically I need to read each line of the file and determine whether the user is in my dictionary, and if it is, whether the tweet contain user's keys in the dictionary (e.g. '@frankgaffney' and '@DavidBartonWB'). So based on the two lines I wrote above, the code should result:

```
d = {{'100022441':{'@frankgaffney': 1, '@DavidBartonWB': 1 }}
```

But it gives:

```
d = {{'100022441':{'@frankgaffney': 1, '@DavidBartonWB': 0 }}
```

For some reason the code always loses one of the keys for all users. Any idea what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is tab delimited, and you are always checking the third column for the mention; it works correctly for the first mention because you are passing in the entire file to the function, not each line. So effectively you are doing this:

```
>>> s = '100022441\t@DavidBartonWB Guarding Constitution\n100022441\tRT@frankgaffney 2nd Amendment Guy.'
>>> s.split('\t')
['100022441', '@DavidBartonWB Guarding Constitution\n100022441', 'RT@frankgaffney 2nd Amendment Guy.']
```

I recommend two approaches:

1. Map your function to each *line* in the file.
2. Use regular expressions for a more robust search.

Try this version:

```
import re

d = {'100022441':{'@frankgaffney': 0, '@DavidBartonWB': 0}}
e = r'(@\w+)'

def parser(line):
   key, tweet = line.split('\t')
   data = d.get(key)
   if data:
      mentions = re.findall(e, tweet)
      for mention in mentions:
          if mention in data.keys():
              d[key][mention] += 1

with open('~/File.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       parser(line)

print(d)
```

Once you've confirmed its working correctly, then you can multi-process it:

```
import itertools, re
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def parse(queue, d, m):
    while True:
       line = queue.get()
       if line is None:
           return # we are done with this thread
       key, tweet = line.split('\t')
       data = d.get(key)
       e = r'(@\w+)'
       if data:
          mentions = re.findall(e, tweet)
          for mention in mentions:
              if mention in data:
                  if mention not in m:
                     m[mention] = 1
                  else:
                     m[mention] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
     workers = 2
     manager = Manager()

     d = manager.dict()
     d2 = manager.dict()
     d = {'100022441': ['@frankgaffney', '@DavidBartonWB']}

     queue = manager.Queue(workers)

     worker_pool = []
     for i in range(workers):
         p = Process(target=parse, args=(queue, d, d2))
         p.start()
         worker_pool.append(p)

     # Fill the queue with data for the workers
     with open(r'tweets2.txt') as f:
         iters = itertools.chain(f, (None,)*workers)
         for line in iters:
             queue.put(line)

     for p in worker_pool:
         p.join()

     for i,data in d.iteritems():
       print('For ID: {}'.format(i))
       for key in data:
          print(' {} - {}'.format(key, d2[key]))
```

Comment: Many thanks for this great solution. The first code runs perfectly and its pretty fast compared to mine. But the second code (i.e. the multiprocessing one) does not work. It keeps the kernel busy without using CPU and never stops even for a 2-line text file.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the above in a hurry and missed a few things. There is also a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6766) that prevents sub-dictionaries from being updated correctly when used in multi-processing.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working version, that has some compromises to get around the [dictionary update bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6766).

Comment: Many thanks. It still gives some error. I'll work on it and get back to you if I couldn't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

second column is data[1], not data[2]

the fact that data[2] works means that you are splitting into words, not columns

if you want to search for the user key as a separate word (as opposed to substring), you need tweet=data[1:]

if you want to search for a substring you need to split into exactly two pieces: uid,tweet=line.split(None,1)

Comment: Yes, but that was a typo in copying and pasting my code here. In the original code i've written that's correct because my file has more fields than the one here and data[2] is the one I need.

Comment: looking at your code again, the loop "for gn in d[uid].keys():" returns inside the first iteration, so you will never look at all keys

I think what you need to do instead of return is update the dictionary (and continue to other keys)